# How can I make my program return to the beginning in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a really new programmer, just programing for fun. I usually write my programs with a series of while loops to get to different sections of the program at different times. It's probably not the best way, but it's all I know how to do.

For example, I'm working on a little program that runs in a shell meant to solve an equation. Here's part of the program that's supposed to bring you back to the beginning.

```
while loop==4:
    goagain = raw_input("Would you like to do the equation again? (Y/N)")
    if goagain == "Y":
        #Get values again
        loop=2
    elif goagain == "N":
        print "Bye!"
        #End program
        loop=0
    else:
        print"Sorry, that wasn't Y or N. Try again."
```

I have it set so that while loop==2, it gets the values to put into the equation and while loop==0, nothing happens.

The problem I have, though, is that when my loop changes back to 2, the program just ends there. It doesn't want to back in the code to where I told it what to do while loop==2.

So what I need to know is how to get my program to go back to that section. Should I use a different method than the while loops? Or is there a way to get my program to go back to that section?

Thanks!

Comment: try to read and follow some tutorials on programming, this will enhance the fun (really). You can start here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be to do sometihng like this:

```
while True:
    goagain = raw_input("Would you like to do the equation again? (Y/N)")
    if goagain == "Y":
        #Get values again
        pass #or do whatever
    elif goagain == "N":
        print "Bye!"
        #End program
        break
    else:
        print"Sorry, that wasn't Y or N. Try again."
```

Comment: And where is the equation solved? IMHO this suffers from the same problem than the original code: You try to force it into one loop, while it would so much more sensible to use one loop for the equation solving and one for asking the user if he wants to continue.

Comment: @NiklasB this wasn't about solving the equation, just about controlling the loop. I would not write code like that, but it's a matter of style.

Comment: @Dvir: No, it's not a matter of opinion, this is definitely convulted and hard-to-read. I don't think code like that should be recommended to beginners.

Comment: @NiklasB I tried to solve the dude's problem with the least amount of changes, not teach him the art of writing clean code. but removing the complexity of the different values of "loop" at least makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You will only iterate when loop is equal to 4. So for the example you have given loop=2 and loop=0 will have the same affect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the loop condition states:-

```
while loop == 4:
```

This means the loop will be executed as long as the value of the variable 'loop' remains 4. But since you assign 2 to loop, the condition is not satisfied, and control goes out of the loop. One solution would be to change condition as:-

```
while loop == 2:
```

Or, another solution would be to remove the statement assigning 2 to loop altogether.

But, since you are getting the value Y/N in goagain, a better way would be:-

```
done = False
while not done:
  goagain = raw_input("Would you like to do the equation again? (Y/N)")
  if goagain == 'Y':
    #Get values
  elif goagain == "N":
    print "Bye!"
    #End program
    done = True
  else:
    print"Sorry, that wasn't Y or N. Try again."
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing Loop to 2, when the user enters Y? If the user inputs yes, collect the values then execute your equation solver, then loop back.

```
while loop==4:
    goagain = raw_input("Would you like to do the equation again? (Y/N)")
    if goagain == "Y":
        #Get values again
        #Solve your equation here
    elif goagain == "N":
        print "Bye!"
        #End program
        loop=0
    else:
        print"Sorry, that wasn't Y or N. Try again."
```

Comment: Why not use `continue`/`break` instead of that senseless `loop` variable?

Comment: I think the OP was simply using loop as some kind of control value, which is probably not even necessary. An appropriate answer would remove the loop value completely and simple loop until a break is requested.

Comment: @jdi: Exactly my thought. Preferrably, the "ask user if he wants do do it again" should be a separate function, which would simplify the logic a lot.

Comment: Totally agree. Though we don't even know what happens in that block other than a comment placeholder :-)

Comment: @NiklasB. Given the OP is new to programming, I didn't want to overly critique his usage of loops, and instead focus on solving his question which is "how to solve the equation, and continue until the user enters N"

Comment: @Alan: Sorry, but I think this site is here to teach good programming, not only to solve immediate problems. Functions are not rocket science and structuring code properly is *especially* important if you are new to programming. Just look at this part of the question: "I usually write my programs with a series of while loops to get to different sections of the program at different times".

Comment: By the way, this does not really answer the question as well. First thing this code would do is to ask whether the user wants to solve an equation *again*. It should probably solve one first before asking that.

Comment: @NiklasB. If your intent is to teach good programming, either comment on the OP's original question, or create your own answer. Commenting on my answer isn't going to teach anyone.

Comment: @NiklasB. It absolutely solves the question being asked. Run my program in python (make up your own dummy equation to solve) and see if it behaves as expected. You're raising issue with the semantics of the prompt text, which may be confusing, but is outside the scope of this problem.

Comment: I actually agree with niklasB regarding teaching good programming practice where possible and not enabling poor habits by simply fixing immediate problems with the poor habit still unaddressed. It helps people more in the long run.

Comment: "I'm a really new programmer, just programing for fun. I usually write my programs with a series of while loops to get to different sections of the program at different times. It's probably not the best way, but it's all I know how to do. "

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as.. this program will check for a number is it prime and find factorial...

```
while input('Enter yes to start no to exit...: ') == 'yes':
    print('Enter your choice [1] to find prime no. and [2] to calc. factorial.')
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    num = int(input('Enter number: '))
    def prime(number):
        if number == (1 or 2 or 3 or 5 or 7):
            print('%d is a prime number..:)' %number)
        else:
            for x in range(2,number):
                if number%x == 0:
                    print('%d is not a prime number..' %number)
                    break
                else:
                    print('%d is a prime number..' %number)
                    break
    def fact(number):
        fact = 1
        for x in range(1,number+1):
            fact = fact*x
        print('Factorial of %d is %d' %(number,fact))
    switch = { 1:prime , 2:fact}
    try:
        result = switch[choice]
        result(num)
    except KeyError:
        print("I didn't get that...")
```

print('Bye...:)')