# Python - how to go back to specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python since a week.

I am trying to do a testing:

---

```
"Beginning of the Program"
print("Hi Sir and welcome to my calculator")
print("Please select from the below menu your math operation")

MenuOption = input("+ for Add, - for Subtract, * for Multiply, / for Division: ") 

if (MenuOption != "+" and MenuOption != "-" and MenuOption != "*" and MenuOption != "/"):
    print("You have typed wrong character, please try again")
    **# my problem is here, I want it to loop back to MenuOption  line**

else:
    print("Thanks for the correct selection")



FirstNumber = int(input("First Number: "))
SecondNumber = int(input("Second Number: "))

if (MenuOption == "+"):
    print(FirstNumber + SecondNumber)

elif (MenuOption == "-"):
    print(FirstNumber - SecondNumber)              

elif (MenuOption == "*"):
    print(FirstNumber * SecondNumber)

elif (MenuOption == "/"):
    print(FirstNumber / SecondNumber)
```

---

I want the program to start promoting back the MenuOption, when I don't press any of the math signs (+, -, *, /)

Comment: Also see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791912/6243352), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548070/how-can-i-make-my-program-return-to-the-beginning-in-python), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254807/how-to-loop-back-to-the-beginning-of-a-programme-python). [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791882/how-to-make-program-go-back-to-the-top-of-the-code-instead-of-closing), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) which are all related.

Comment: Thank you in worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn loops. If you do the thing `while` the loop expression becomes `false`, It will be running correctly. Set some variable to `false` when one of these signs `+ - / *` will be selected, otherwise, the `flag` variable should be `true`.

**NOTE**

That's because of `python` doesn't support `goto` and `label` either